# Save data in foreign key from DropDownList?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-keys, code-first

I have this two models in a asp.net mvc code first application

```
public class Site
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Turbine> Turbines { get; set; }
}

public class Turbine
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }
}
```

In the Turbine view I want to display a dropdown with all the sites. Post the form and save the selected value (site) from the dropdown as a foreign key in the Turbine table.

I have this `Get`in the controller

```
ViewBag.Sites = new SelectList(db.Sites, "Id", "Name");
return View(db.Turbines.ToList());
```

And this is my Turbine view within a form post

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Site.Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Sites, "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And this is my post controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Site")] Turbine turbine)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.Turbines.Add(turbine);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(turbine);
}
```

`Id` and `Name` are saved correctly in the `Turbine` table. But I also get a new row with a strange `Id` (rest is null) in the `Site` table and the same Id as a foreign key in the Turbine table.

I want to list all the Sites in a DropDownList when I create a new Turbine and save that Id (which is primary key in the Site table) as a foreign key in the Turbine table. I don't want to create a new row in the Site table when I create a new Turbine, I want to use the existing Id in the Site table.

Comment: Your `Turbine` model needs navigation property to the `Sites` table - e.g. public int SiteID { get; set; }` (and you bind the selected value to `SiteID`)

Comment: Thought I did that with "virtual" I have a FK column generated in my Turbine table.

Comment: You still need to navigation property :)

Comment: Ok, is the rest of my code correct?

Comment: Still not working. Can you give me larger example? My Id in Site is just Id and not SiteID. Should I still use SiteID?

Comment: Suggest you start by reading [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj713564.aspx). All this will be handled out of the box is the field in the `Site` table is `SiteID` rather than `ID`, but you can use the `[ForeignKey]` attribute to specify the mapping. Refer also [this article](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)